# Obtener en tiempo real el valor de un select en php-js-ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Tengo un pequeño problema que no se como resolver. Tengo un desplegable para seleccionar entre 3 opciones y al lado un input para escribir y realizar busquedas.

Cuando empiezas a escribir en el input va mostrando los datos que coinciden de la bbdd, pero los datos que muestra siempre son de la misma tabla. (En la query esta puesto el nombre de la tabla en vez de una variable)

Lo que quiero conseguir es que dependiendo que opción selecciones en el desplegable, luego cuando escribas muestre los datos de una u otra tabla.

El input es como autocompletar automáticamente en tiempo real.

Como puedo pasar en tiempo real el valor del desplegable a una variable para ponerlo en la query?

**actualizacion**

En mi pagina principal tengo esto:

```
<select required name="name" id="name" class="form-control" onchange="send(this.value);">
<option value="name1">name1</option>
<option value="name2">name2</option>
</select>

<script>
  function send(name) {
     //var dataString = "name" + name;
      $.ajax({  
      type: 'POST',  
      url: 'ajax.php', 
      data: {name: name},
      });
   }
</script>
```

Y en la otra pagina trato de recoger el valor de esta forma, pero devuelve null.

```
$name =$_post['name'];
var_dump($name);
die();
```

Comment: Por favor agrega un [mcve] a tu pregunta, lo que expones no es suficiente para intentar adivinar lo que pretendes hacer. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras añadí el codigo

Comment: Me parece que se trata de un error tipográfico, la variable correcta en PHP es `$_POST`, en mayúsculas.